# hunspell from java with personal dictionary

Tags: java, jna, hunspell, bridj

I have two options to use hunspell from java:

- Hunspell JNA or
- Hunspell BridJ

Both of them works fine, but I would like to use the "personal dictionary" feature of hunspell (when calling hunspell from command line, the -p parameter).

Is there a way to use Hunspell JNA or BridJ with this parameter, or with the same funcionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by looing at the C++ source of Hunspell, I finally figured it out; the Hunspell library doesn't use personal dictionaries - only the Hunspell CLI (Command Line Interface) uses it, so there is no way (unless you write your own custom code) to use it from JNA or BridJ.

Comment: I doubt the answer. This is the most common use case. I don't think library developers haven't thought about this. Can you explain this with code snippets for how did you came up with above conclusion?